# passing parameter from javascript to servlet

Tags: java, javascript, html, servlets

I am retrieving all the contacts of a user from gmail and yahoo, I have added the checkbox, the user needs to select the desired email id to which he need to send email. I need to collect all user selected email id's and save them in a string send that string to another servlet where I am sending emails.

I was able to add the check box dynamically but I am not able to collect the emails and save them in a string. This is the code I have written to add check box before all the emails, 
kindly help me to put those selected email id's in a string

I used the following code, but still I am not able to do it.You can have a look at the demo of this app http://ec2-50-16-183-101.compute-1.amazonaws.com/SocialAuthNew/
To get the contacts from Gmail type google in the text box and for yahoo type yahoo and click on submit button

```
 List<Contact> contactsList = provider.getContactList();
                    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();  
                    out.println("<html>");
                    out.println("<head><script type='text/javascript'>");
                    out.println("function getAllContacts(size){ var selected_list='';");
                    out.println("for(var c=0;c<size;c++){if(document.getElementById('mailCheckbox'+c).checked==true){selected_list=selected_list+document.getElementById('lblmail'+c).innerHTML+':';}}");
                    out.println("document.getElementById('final_mailing_list').innerHTML=selected_list;}</script>");
                    out.println("<title></title>");
                    out.println("</head>");
                    out.println("<body>");

                    for(int i=0;i<contactsList.size();i++){
                        System.out.println(contactsList.get(i).getFirstName()+" : "+contactsList.get(i).getLastName()+":"+contactsList.get(i).getEmail());

                        out.println("<h1> Imported conatcts from your mail are:-</h1>");
                        out.println("<input type='checkbox' id='mailCheckBox"+i+"' name='mailCheckbox'></input>");
                      /*  out.println(contactsList.get(i).getFirstName());
                        out.println(contactsList.get(i).getLastName());*/
                        out.println("<label id='lblmail"+i+"'>"+contactsList.get(i).getEmail()+"</label>");
                    }
                    int size=contactsList.size();
                    out.println("<input type='button' value='GetContact' onclick='getAllContacts("+size+");'/> ");
                    out.println("<div id='final_mailing_list'></div></body>");
                    out.println("</html>");
                }
```

Comment: HTML belongs in JSP, not in servlet. It'll make your life (and JavaScript stuff) **A LOT** easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

s using array is much easier. i have used array and gave the check box name as check1 and on the click of submit button i have called the following function. this function alerts the value of the selected check boxes and passes the action to servlet

```
<script>
function onCallForInterview()
{
var selectedIds;
var count=0;
for (i=0; i<document.frm.check1.length; i++)
{
if (document.frm.check1[i].checked==true)
{
if(count==0){
selectedIds=document.frm.check1[i].value; 
count=count+1; 
}
else
selectedIds=selectedIds+","+document.frm.check1[i].value;
}
}
alert(selectedIds);  
document.frm.action="<%=contextPath%>/SearchCandInfo?    action=selectcanforinterview&ids="+selectedIds;
document.frm.submit();
}
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for the help I tried the logic which u suggested, I guess the I have done something wrong. I am not able to get the desired out put. Kindly have a look.

Comment: just call this function onclick='getAllContacts()'; and in the function u should take the length of the check box ie mailcheckbox.length() try this i have used array in my prog and it is working fine but u r using for loop so check if the above suggestion helps u .

Comment: <input type='checkbox' id='mailCheckBox"+i+"' name='mailCheckbox'> in this line add something like this value="contactsList.get(i).getEmail()" so that each check box created dynamically will have a unique value

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

1) Wrap your email in a DOM element to make it easier to access

```
out.println("<span>" + contactsList.get(i).getEmail() + "</span>");
```

2) Using something like e.g. [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) for normalizing access to the DOM on the client, do

```
function getSelectedEmails() {
  var emails = [];
  $('body').find('input[name="mailCheckbox"]:checked').each(function() {
    emails.push($(this).closest('span').text());
  });
  return emails;
}
```

This returns the emails in an array - which you can easily concatenate into a string if you want with e.g.

```
var emailString = emails.join(", ");
```

...although I think using an array is usually better (perhaps JSON encoded if you need to serialize it).

Comment: Hello I made some changes in the code. and I have posted here, kindly have a look and please help me.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly more primitive way to achieve this,

Create a bunch of Check-Box as you are doing now but with the difference that all of htem should have the same name i.e. do the following correction in your code

```
out.println("<input type='checkbox' id='mailCheckBox' name='mailCheckbox'></input>");
```

Now retrieve all the values of such text boxes on your server side using following call on request object,

```
            String[] emailIds = request.getParameterValues("mailCheckBox");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It is not valid HTML to have multiple DOM elements with the same ID.

Comment: @Jeevan: You need not do any change in your html generation code. Just use it. My approach just need the same parameter name. IDs could be different.